# How to solve sorting of different balls by collection

Tags: java, eclipse

Suppose I have one container that contain different
colors of ballons

- such as Red, Blue, Green, Red,Blue,Red, Blue, Green in
  this order,
- now sort that baloon in such manner so Red baloon will be
  added first
- then Blue baloon and last is Green balloons. Use the
  proper collection

Comment: Use a `List`. Call `List#sort(Comparator)`. Pass a `Comparator` that defines the ordering you described. If you already have some code, but you're having a _specific_ problem, then please demonstrate that problem with a [mre].

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your *colors* an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Balloons {
    enum Colors {RED, BLUE, GREEN}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Colors> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(Colors.RED);
        list.add(Colors.BLUE);
        list.add(Colors.GREEN);
        list.add(Colors.RED);
        list.add(Colors.BLUE);
        list.add(Colors.RED);
        list.add(Colors.BLUE);
        list.add(Colors.GREEN);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Running above code outputs the following:

```
[RED, RED, RED, BLUE, BLUE, BLUE, GREEN, GREEN]
```

Alternatively, if your *colors* are strings, define an appropriate comparator.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Balloons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Red");
        list.add("Blue");
        list.add("Green");
        list.add("Red");
        list.add("Blue");
        list.add("Red");
        list.add("Blue");
        list.add("Green");
        Comparator<String> c = (s1, s2) -> {
            if ("Red".equals(s1)) {
                if ("Red".equals(s2)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return -1;
            }
            else if ("Blue".equals(s1)) {
                if ("Red".equals(s2)) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else if ("Blue".equals(s2)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                if ("Green".equals(s2)) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return 1;
            }
        };
        list.sort(c);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```